# Javascript confirm box to open link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `href` as follows:

```
<a class="eLink" href="http:www.abc.com">chk here xyz</a></li>
```

and javascript for "eLink" is as follows:

```
$("a.eLink").click(function link(evt) {
        url = evt.target.href;

        if (url.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(".gov") <= 0) {
            
            var tk = "Do you really want to continue?";

            if (confirm(tk)) {
                window.open(url, 'newwin');
            }
        } else {
            window.open(url, 'newwin');
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

Now, when click the hyperlink I get the message "Do you really want to continue?", now When I click 'yes' it opens a new browser with the target page "abc.com" and my current browser also changes to "abc.com".

I want to change the code in such a way that the current browser remains in the same page and target browser "abc.com" opens in the new page, and if I click "No", the browser should remain in the same page.

I tried using them in a plain javascript with confirm boxes, but the problem is wherever I have to use this code, the external browser link has to be given in the javascript, which I want to avoid.

Is there a quick change in the above script that would accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 1):

Use '_self' to refer to the current window/tab. See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp for more details.

```
$("a.eLink").click(function link(evt) {
    url = evt.target.href;

    if (url.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(".gov") <= 0) {

        var tk = "Do you really want to continue?";

        if (confirm(tk)) {
            window.open(url, 'newwin');
        }
    }
    else
    { window.open(url, '_self'); } // open in same tab/page

    return false;
 });
});


// if you click yes, redirect, if no, then do nothing
if (confirm(tk)) {
   window.open(url, 'newwin');
} else {
   return false; // do nothing
}
```

Comment: thanks jmort253...another Question is when i click "No" my browser should remain in the same page( i mean it shouldnt goto "abc.com")...browser shdnt be changed. Rightnow with '_self' it doesnt open a target window but browser changes to "abc.com"

Comment: @javaiText - Just use an if else block to split up the behavior based on the specific input of the user. For instance, if the confirm result is false, then control should transfer to the else block.

Comment: @jmort253. else with return false didnt help. a href already contains abc.com as the resulting target..is that the reason, cancel also opens abc.com? now sure though.

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` may help you as well.

Answer (score 1):

working for me http://jsfiddle.net/8vKvT/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a.eLink").click(function link(evt) {
    url = evt.target.href;

    if (url.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(".gov") <= 0) {

        var tk = "Do you really want to continue?";

        if (confirm(tk)) {
            window.open(url, 'newwin');
        } else {
            window.open(url, '_self');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        window.open(url, 'newwin');
    }

    return false;
});
```

Comment: thanks Jordan...another Question is when i click "No" my browser should remain in the same page( i mean it shouldnt goto "abc.com")...browser shdnt be changed. Rightnow with '_self' it doesnt open a target window but browser changes to "abc.com"